# Why does slice() in javascript accept float values?

Tags: javascript

I thought following would throw an error but it accepted float indices.

```js
var str = 'Why does slice() in javascript accept float values?';
console.log(str.slice(4,8.5));
console.log(str.slice(9.5,16.5));
```

Comment: There's only "floats" in JS, there's no integer type.

Comment: [22.1.3.22 `Array.prototype.slice()`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.slice) -> Step 5: `Let relativeStart be ToInteger(start).`

Comment: @Andreas shows you how to take "guess work" out of your programming process

Comment: @Teemu if thats the case why arrays cant have float indices ?

Comment: @ShoyebSheikh — They, like any other object, can have properties with any string or symbol value. Indexes are a special case and are generated from the properties on the object which are integers.

Comment: [Who says they can't](https://jsfiddle.net/d2469z7t/)? Though that'll create a property to the array itself, not a member to the array ...

Comment: @Teemu my bad just checked arrays can have float indices ty guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [ECMA-262 specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.slice).

> 3. Let *relativeStart* be ? ToInteger(*start*).

and

> 5. If end is undefined, let *relativeEnd* be *len*; else let *relativeEnd* be ? ToInteger(*end*).

It makes a best effort attempt to convert *whatever* input it is given into an integer.

This is pretty standard across all of JavaScript. It almost always prefers type conversion over exception throwing.